# Why does a mouse right click fire the "pointerdown" event when pressed down but not the "pointerup" event when released?

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, pointer-events

I'm using [pointerevents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Pointer_events) rather than mouse events to be able to have a universal pointer solution, rather than having to separately consider touch vs mouse events etc.

The problem is that when I press the right mouse button, the pointerdown event is fired normally (as expected), but when releasing it, the pointerup event is not fired (unexpectedly).

I've created a minimum reproducible case here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-smoke-1x2w5?file=/src/index.js

And I've created a video of the issue here:
https://app.usebubbles.com/6a21646e-13d2-4a7f-a598-dfad35a9c0d3

Why does a mouse right click fire the "pointerdown" event when pressed down but not the "pointerup" event when released?

Note that this is in Chrome 81 (https://www.whatsmybrowser.org/b/VJUHP)

Answer (score 1):

It appears to have to do with the [`"contextmenu"`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/contextmenu_event), check the snippet below, if you prevent the default behaviour then the `"pointerup"` event is triggered on the right click.

```js
const app = document.getElementById("app");
const count = document.getElementById("count");

const writeCount = (n) => (count.innerHTML = n);

noContextMenu.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
});

let n = 0;
writeCount(0);

app.addEventListener("pointerdown", (e) => {
  writeCount(++n);
  eventType.innerHTML = "pointerdown";
});

app.addEventListener("pointerup", (e) => {
  writeCount(--n);
  eventType.innerHTML = "pointerup";
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#contextmenu {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}

#noContextMenu {
  margin: 10px;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  float: left;
  border: 1px solid darkviolet;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>
    Event type: (<span id="count"></span>) <span id="eventType"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="contextmenu">context menu</div>
  <div id="noContextMenu">noContextMenu</div>
</div>
```

Comment: seems like this is a chrome bug then?

Comment: I don't think so, I was trying to investigate this further. It appears that the right click is not really a "pointer event", let me update my answer with a few extra divs and then you'll see that when we log the right click event it doesn't have the type pointer, so maybe that's why "pointerup" is not triggered.

Comment: If it's not a pointer event, then why would pointerdown be fired?

Comment: You're right, it does seem to be a pointer event :) I'll investigate this further, curious to know as well.

Comment: Giving up for now, I think you might be right and there's a bug in Chrome when it comes to firing `pointerup` after the context menu being opened. I wonder if there's a reason for that, maybe we cannot fire pointer up while the menu is opened because then how do you detect a click on it? I'm not sure, but really curious to know.

Comment: I feel like it should at least fire `pointercancel` in that case

Comment: I think `contextmenu` triggers `pointercancel` which indicates that no `pointerup` will be forthcoming.